# UIPicker selection from NSUserDefaults in double value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uipickerviewcontroller

I'm beginner developer...
I have NSUserDefaults to get UIPicker selection and a double value where to load selection of the UIPicker.

```
 NSUserDefaults *pickerViewSelectionDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [pickerWork selectRow:[pickerViewSelectionDefaults integerForKey:@"pickerSelectionMinWork"] inComponent:0 animated:YES];

double dobMinute = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [[minArray objectAtIndex:[pickerWork selectedRowInComponent:0]] floatValue]] doubleValue]*60;
```

How can I replace **selectedRowInComponent:** with **selectRow:inComponent:animated:** because I have this error:

Sending 'void' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long')

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you get the error?

Comment: @anhtu https://www.dropbox.com/s/uemccj6urji0vud/error.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

change

```
  double dobMinute = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [[minArray objectAtIndex:[pickerWork selectedRowInComponent:0]] floatValue]] doubleValue]*60;
```

to

```
double dobMinute = [pickerViewSelectionDefaults integerForKey:@"pickerSelectionMinWork"]*60;
```

Comment: Because with only  '[[minArray objectAtIndex:[pickerWork selectedRowInComponent:0]] floatValue]*60' I can't get NSUserDefaults value. Then I need a float for a countdown. https://www.dropbox.com/s/uemccj6urji0vud/error.png?dl=0

Comment: In your img, you didn't use "[pickerWork selectedRowInComponent:0]". You are using [pickerWork selectRow:[pickerViewSelectionDefaults integerForKey:@"pickerSelectionMinWork"] inComponent:0 animated:YES]. Change it.

Comment: You ask me what line caused the error? I replaced [pickerWork selectedRowInComponent:0] with [pickerWork selectRow:[pickerViewSelectionDefaults integerForKey:@"pickerSelectionMinWork"] inComponent:0 animated:YES] to show you the error. I can't solve this error.

Comment: It means  [pickerWork selectedRowInComponent:0]  cause error also?. [minArray objectAtIndex:....] this function need a int value. [pickerWork selectRow:[pickerViewSelectionDefaults integerForKey:@"pickerSelectionMinWork"] inComponent:0 animated:YES] doesn't return any value. So, you got the error for sure.

Comment: Does "double dobMinute = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [[minArray objectAtIndex:[pickerWork selectedRowInComponent:0]] floatValue]] doubleValue]*60;" cause any error? I don't understand what do you want. Can you make the problem clearly?

Comment: "[[minArray objectAtIndex:[pickerWork selectedRowInComponent:0]] floatValue]*60" works! But I need to remember the picker selection with NSUserDefaults. So to select row I set selectRow:inComponent:animated: with selectRow:[pickerViewSelectionDefaults integerForKey:@"pickerSelectionMinWork"] instead of method selectedRowInComponent:0